# Facebook v2 integration with iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, email, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I was trying to integrate Facebook SDK with v2 Api.
As Facebook allow the user to declined any permission that he don't want to share (mostly email).
But as our requirements we need the user's email to register them to server (email is primary key) and email is also used to connect the user in many ways.

I've some doubts about it.

1. I was wondering to make email as required permission.
2. As mentioned in Facebook upgrading guide we can re-ask user about declined permissions
   [Re-asking for Declined Permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#v2_0_login_optional_permissions)

Here is the sample of code trying to do while re-asking but do not get the email of user

```
    [[FBSession activeSession] requestNewReadPermissions:@[@"user_birthday",@"email"] completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
          if (session.state == FBSessionStateOpen) {
               [FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id<FBGraphUser> facebook_user, NSError *error) {
                      if (error) {
                              [self fbRequestFailedWithError:error];
                      } else {
                              [self processFacebookRequest:facebook_user];
                      }
              }];
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make email a required permission, see here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#v2_0_login_optional_permissions

Not all users will have an email address available even if they grant your app the permission - users who signed up for Facebook via their mobile phone number, whose email address bounces or requires reverification will not have an email available via the API

Your code looks like the code for re-requesting permissions, but it's also possible you're already being granted the permission but the user has no email address